# Getting an error on an each in my jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a simple function to build a form using the same code base I have used many times.  In this form I am adding a select object.  Everything works except for the select object is not not working. I am using an ajax function to call the data from a database table. When troubleshooting, I am getting the data 
back when looking at network on chrome but in the console I am getting the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.
Here is the data returned from the ajax call.

```
{"oshadaytype":[
{"oshadaytypeid":3,"oshadaytype":"Job Transfer"},
{"oshadaytypeid":2,"oshadaytype":"Light Days"},
{"oshadaytypeid":1,"oshadaytype":"Lost Days"} 
]}
```

Here is the jquery function. Everything is working except I am getting the empty select object.

```
$(function(){
    $("#addoshadaysbutton").click(function(){
        $.ajax({type:   "GET",url:    '../posttimetosession.php'}).done();
        $("#addoshadaysdiv").empty();
        $.ajax({type:   "GET",url:    '../json/getoshadayjson.php'}).done(function(data){
            $("#addoshadaysdiv").append(
                $('<div>').append(
                    $('<label>').text("OSHA Days").addClass("rmargin3 subtitle")
                ).addClass("paddingbottom3")   
            ).append(
                $('<div>').append(
                    $('<input>').prop({type:"submit",name:"addoshadayssubmit",value:"Save OSHA Days"}).addClass("button")
                ).addClass("paddingbottom3")
            ).append(
                $('<div>').append(
                    $('<label>').prop({for:"oshastartdate"}).text("Start Date:").addClass("rmargin3")
                ).append(
                    $('<input>').attr({type: 'text',id: 'oshastartdate',name: 'oshastartdate'}).addClass("datepick eighth rmargin10")
                ).append(
                    $('<label>').prop({for:"oshaenddate"}).text("End Date:").addClass("rmargin3")
                ).append(
                    $('<input>').attr({type: 'text',id: 'oshaenddate',name: 'oshaenddate'}).addClass("datepick eighth rmargin10")
                ).append(
                    $('<label>').prop({for:"oshadaytypeid"}).text("OSHA Days Type:").addClass("rmargin3")
                ).append(
                    $('<select>').attr({id: "oshadaytypeid",name: "oshadaytypeid"})
                )                 
            )
            $.each(data.oshadaytype,function(key,value){
                $("#oshadaytypeid").append(
                    $('<option>').prop({value:value.oshadaytypeid}).text(value.oshadaytype)
                )   
            })       
        });
    })
})
```

The error points to the beginning of the each function.

```
$.each(data.oshadaytype,function(index,value)
```

Any ideas on this.  It has got to be something simple.
Here is the php code.

```
unset($_SESSION['oshadays']);
$appquery = "select * from hrs.oshadaytypes order by oshadaytype";
$results=sqlsrv_query($link,$appquery,array(),array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die('Cannot get the nonemployee record');  
if(sqlsrv_has_rows($results)){
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $_SESSION['oshadays']['oshadaytype'][]=$row;        
    }
}
echo json_encode($_SESSION['oshadays']);
```

Comment: What's the actual error?

Comment: what does `console.log(typeof data)` output? and also set `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call.

Comment: The chrome consolepoint so the $.each function stating
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. 
There is no other error I can find anywhere. My php log is clean.

Comment: Are you 100% sure `data` contains what you think it does?

Comment: I am pulling the data from the chrome network pane as I always do.

Comment: I added an alert in the each function just to see if it gets that far and it didn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All assumptions here. The returned data looks like a JSON string. Hence you have 2 options.

## 1:

Set data type of your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({type: "GET", dataType: 'json', url: '../json/getoshadayjson.php'}).done(function(data){
```

Beacuse dataType is the type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response.

## 2:

[Parse the JSON String](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

```
var _data = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(_data.oshadaytype,function(key,value){
```

Comment: That's it. I didn't set the dataType.  Stupid me.  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but perhaps the AJAX return data is not being parsed as JSON for some reason, and is still a string.  Then `data.oshadaytype` would be undefined.  Try this:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data).oshadaytype,function(key,value){
```